# Apache Zeppelin Set Max Output Limit

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I have a piece of code that just does the simplest thing in life as below:

```
%python

import pandas as pd

datas_path = 'target/youtube_videos.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(datas_path, sep=';')
df_first_3 = df.head(3)
print(df_first_3)
```

The output as expected:

```
  channel_title                channel_id  ... comments_views_ratio mean_views_day
0   somename1  ajshdjaksdhksdjj...             0.002138   71086.125000
1   somename2  uaszduahdkuhghkg...             0.002350   74721.562500
2   somename3  ajksdhhagsdkkkkk...             0.002815    6167.171717
```

But it is truncated. I tried to set this property in the zeppelin-site.xml as below, but it does not respect that:

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit</name>
  <value>25000000</value>
  <description>Output message from interpreter exceeding the limit will be truncated</description>
</property>
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: I even tried to use 102400000 but it does not respect. Ofcourse I did a restart of the Zeppelin service°

Comment: You might want to use the Zeppelin table instead, like `z.show(df_first_3)`.